# Regex with whitespaces and preceding zeros

Tags: regex, sas

I want to match the string `11` with a regular Expression in SAS. 
The `11` can be preceded by zero or more 0 and/or by white spaces. Any other character is not allowed.
Likewise, if anything there should only be white spaces following the `11`.

Examples:

```
Match:
0000011  
11
11<space><space>

No Match:
115
400011
```

So far, I am using `/^[\s|0+]11\s*$/` . It works, but I was wondering if there is an approach that is more straightforward?

Comment: `[\s|0+]` means whitespace, |, 0 or +. why not `/^\s*0*11\s*$/`?

Comment: What do you mean " if anything there should only be white spaces following the 0"? Can you illustrate with examples?

Comment: @Bohemian: thanks for the hint. Should be a 11 and not a 0. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simplified regex:

```
/^[\s0]*11\s*$/
```

Comment: How does this work if there is whitespace after the '11' match?  Also, won't this match the characters preceding the '11', even though @Tom wanted only the '11' matches?

Comment: @jrahhali: Didn't understand your comment. OP wrote `The 11 can be preceded by zero or more 0 and/or by white spaces`. This will allow `0 or more spaces followed by 0 or more zeroes followed by 11`.

Comment: @Tom: Did you find anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: I mean, your regex ends in a `11$`, but doesn't the OP instead want `11\s*$`?  Also, your `\s*0*` means that spaces and zeros will be part of the match, even though the OP only wanted `11`.  Further, `\s*0*` requires that all whitespace comes before zeros, but the OP requires that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: In that case updated regex should satisfy the requirement I think.

Comment: @anubhava: perfect, that`s exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems fine. I am not used to SAS's regex but it appears like you allow only one space and require at least one 0 before the 11.

The following should work too, allowing many or no space and zeroes before the 11 (zeroes and speces can be mingled), and forbidding any other characters than spaces after.

```
/^[\s|0]*11\s*$/
```

I am not sure you can really do better in your use case.